# how to specify dynamic class loader with eclipse link

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, odata4j

Environment :
Tomcat- web server, eclipselink-2.4.1(Juno)  JPA, Odata4j
I'm doing JPA (Generate dynamic entities from table) with eclipse link. 
My persistence.xml looks like

```
<persistence-unit name="abcLink"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <mapping-file>META-INF/eclipselink-orm.xml</mapping-file>           
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/netspectiveauthentication?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.exceptions" value="true" />     
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

and 
 In provider class

```
String persistenceUnitName = "abcLink";      
          EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnitName,properties);
            emf.createEntityManager();                   
            return new JPAProducer(emf, "abcd", 20);
```

I'm using this for ODATA4j implementation , so properties will get by overriding 
ODataProducer create function 
while running I'm getting the following error

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28017] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Unable to predeploy PersistenceUnit [AuthenticationServiceEclipseMysqlLink] in invalid state [DeployFailed].
Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [AuthenticationServiceEclipseMysqlLink] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7328] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: When using VIRTUAL access a DynamicClassLoader must be provided when creating the entity manager factory using the eclipselink property [eclipselink.classloader]. That is, createEntityManagerFactory(String persistenceUnitName, Map properties) and add a new DynamicClassLoader() to the Map properties.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1226)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:134)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source)
```

I think error is clear but I want to know, How can I give dynamic classloader through properties. or any other way to get-rid-off this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this example](http://old.nabble.com/attachment/31108217/0/TestSingleQuery.java), at the beginning of the `main` method.

Comment: Thanks for the sample. I set class loader with the help of ur sample file. afther that I got an error which specifies in the https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=397283. So No progress with dynamic. temporarily stopped dynamic, now checking with static classes. Any way could you please suggest  where I can find these type of examples.

Comment: Google :) Seriously, you should identify a sub-string of the error message that contains important keywords, and Google the sub-string. For example: https://www.google.com/search?q=add+a+new+DynamicClassLoader()+to+the+Map+properties&oq=add+a+new+DynamicClassLoader()+to+the+Map+properties